# MySQL não utiliza o indice na query (inner join)

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma *query* que esta demorando para ser executada, analisando o *explain* vejo que o MySQL não esta utilizando o indice em uma das tabelas.

Tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE `rel_financeiro` (
  `protocolo` char(13) NOT NULL,
  `aceito` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `processado` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `valor_previsto` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `valor_pago` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`registro`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `emails` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `data` datetime NOT NULL,
  `de` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `para` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `protocolo` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assunto` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pasta` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `lido` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `headers` text NOT NULL,
  `mensagem` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `protocolo` (`protocolo`),
  KEY `pasta` (`pasta`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Query:

```
SELECT r.protocolo, r.aceito, r.valor_previsto
  FROM rel_financeiro r
 INNER JOIN emails e ON r.protocolo = e.protocolo
 WHERE e.id IN ('e665a3e5-098f-a754-d4fe-5602a15aa191', '39b191b3-8f04-11e5-b9b8-040166406e01', '3e6c68ee-8f04-11e5-b9b8-040166406e01');
```

Resultado do explain:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys     | key     | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e     | const | PRIMARY,protocolo | PRIMARY | 108     | const |       1 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r     | ALL   | NULL              | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  | 5197139 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
```

Já tentei de várias formas diferentes e até agora nada.

Comment: Tarcio, que bom que você resolveu seu problema. Se você quiser postar uma resposta com os comandos `INSERT \ SELECT` que resolveram seu problema tenho certeza que a informação será bem vinda para a comunidade. Dito isso, seria legal obter alguns `dumps` que reproduzisem o problema, dessa maneira saímos desse impasse de uma não-pergunta com duas ou três não-respostas.

Comment: Quando eu criei as tabelas ocultando informações confidenciais (como você sugeriu), tudo funcionou, daí eu cheguei a solução, é maluco, mas é isso. Se eu fornecer um dump será justamente da tabela sem o problema.

Comment: Tarcio, reverti suas edições. A primeira invalidava as respostas existentes. A segunda é melhor postar ali embaixo, na área de respostas. Não tem problema responder a própria pergunta, mas precisa usar a parte de baixo, e não embutir a resposta na pergunta.

Answer (score 3):

Seu create table está definindo uma chave primária com uma coluna que não existe, `registro`.
Talvez a intenção fosse

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`protocolo`)
```

Se a chave primária desejada for mesmo a que já está definida, crie um índice:

```
  KEY (`protocolo`)
```

ou índice único

```
  UNIQUE (`protocolo`)
```

Conforme apropriado.

Comment: A KEY correta é protocolo, fiz tantos testes mudando a estrutura da tabela que nem percebi o erro, obrigado por reparar.

Answer (score 3):

Assumindo que `protocolo` seja a *PK* de `rel_financeiro` como apontado na [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/99363/100) do [fbiazi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/14110/fbiazi), o problema parece ser a posição do join:

```
SELECT r.protocolo, r.aceito, r.valor_previsto
  FROM emails e 
 INNER JOIN rel_financeiro r ON r.protocolo = e.protocolo 
 WHERE e.id IN ('e665a3e5-098f-a754-d4fe-5602a15aa191', '39b191b3-8f04-11e5-b9b8-040166406e01', '3e6c68ee-8f04-11e5-b9b8-040166406e01');
```

[image: EXPLAIN query original]

Você quer que o `from` seja a tabela **emails** para que a cláusula `where` use o índice de `id` e reduza **emails** para um pequeno conjunto de dados. Depois disso o `join` pode utilizar o índice em `protocolo`.

É claro que o otimizador de *queries* poderia fazer a parte dele e chegar a uma conclusão semelhante sozinho, porém não há garantias nesse caso. Veja o resultado que recebi com sua *query* original:

[image: EXPLAIN query alterada]

O MySQL está sendo bem literal, trazendo todos os **rel_financeiro** para memória primeiro e só então tentando fazer o `join` do resultado com os **emails**.

---

[**Exemplo funcional no SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f04b/13)

Comment: Rodando em uma tabela vazia o resultado é realmente esse, mas quando temos registros (5 milhoes em uma tabela e 300 mil na outra) volta a não utilizar a KEY, mesmo com o seu exemplo (que realmente esta melhor que o meu)

Comment: 5 milhões em **rel_financeiro** e 300k em **emails**? Eu acho que o otimizador está se perdendo... Já tentou rodar [ANALYZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/analyze-table.html) em ambas as tabelas e repetir a consulta?

Comment: sim ja rodei o ANALYSE TABLE, e não mudou nada, já recriei as tabelas em outra base, levando um dump com os dados e nada.

Comment: Eu ainda usaria um outer join nesse caso, não que eu ache que isso vai mudar o problema. Mais especificamente um LEFT JOIN com a tabela emails na esquerda (imagino que o _planner_ já faça isso automaticamente, entretanto). Nota: se houver expectativa de muitas leituras sequenciais, o MySQL abandona o index em favor do full scan. Um bom _benchmark_ seria rodar sem o IN, usando =, e talvez fazendo queries separadas para cada id.

Comment: Concordo com o Bacco sobre o `LEFT JOIN`. Fica bem difícil testar sem uma carga de dados. Você consegue gerar uma massa de dados *fake*  que simule o problema? (No pior dos casos um *dump* compactado depois de mascarar todos os dados confidenciais).

Comment: Agora a coisa ficou mais maluca... gerei uma base ocultando os dados confidenciais (como conteúdo dos emails, endereços etc), e surpresa o índice funciona com estas novas tabelas de teste que criei. A estrutura é exatamente a mesma, a unica diferença é conteúdo de algumas colunas que nem mesmo estão sendo utilizadas na query.